# How to clone object with a different Primary Key

Tags: c#, .net, realm

I have this class Cart_Record, shown below. I want to update the PrimaryKey. To do that I am trying to clone the object into a new object to copy CartLines and update ID. I haven't found much in the issue queue or the documentation to help me.

```
public class Cart_Record : RealmObject
{
    public Cart_Record() { }

    public Cart_Record(IList<Cart_Line> cartLines, int id)
    {
        ID = id;
        foreach (var cartLine in cartLines)
            CartLines.Add(App.RealmDB.Find<Cart_Line>(cartLine.ProductId));
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IList<Cart_Line> CartLines { get; }
}
```

I am trying this

```
var appCart = App.RealmDB.All<Cart_Record>().First();

App.RealmDB.Write(() =>
{
    var cartLines = new List<Cart_Line>(appCart.CartLines);
    App.RealmDB.Remove(App.RealmDB.Find<Cart_Record>(appCart.ID));
    App.RealmDB.Add<Cart_Record>(new Cart_Record(cartLines, serverCart.ID));
});
```

However I keep getting exceptions, specifically RealmObjectManagedByAnotherRealmException. I don't understand how as I am not readding the Cart_Line objects to Realm, just to the CartLine list in the new object.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks ahead of time.

Edit: I found something that works but I would like to see if someone else have a better method. This is what works for me.

```
var appCart = App.RealmDB.All<Cart_Record>().First();                       
App.RealmDB.Write(() =>
{
    var cartLines = new List<Cart_Line>(appCart.CartLines);
    App.RealmDB.Remove(App.RealmDB.Find<Cart_Record>(appCart.ID));
    var newAppCart = App.RealmDB.Add<Cart_Record>(new Cart_Record() { ID = serverCart.ID });
    foreach (var cartLine in cartLines)
        newAppCart.CartLines.Add(cartLine);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `App.RealmDB` does under the hood, but using the out-of-the-box Realm API, what you want to achieve can be done by simply adding the CartLines from the original to the updated object:

```
// Assume want to change Id from 1 to 2
var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
var original = realm.Find<Cart_Record>(1); 

var updated = new Cart_Record { ID = 2 }; // other properties must be copied here
foreach (var cart in original.CartLines)
{
    updated.CartLines.Add(cart);
}

realm.Write(() =>
{
    realm.Remove(original);
    realm.Add(updated);
});

// updated now has all the original's CartLines
```